# Populate the maximum value without a join oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 3 columns VALUE1, step,date with values as given below....Now i want a view with a 4th column like below picture. for example, the maximum  value of date for value1 '1' is 13.3.2014 and its corresponding step is C...So, the value of max(step-date) for '1' should be 'C' and so on. I want to do this without performing a join on the table itself. Hope am clear in my requirement. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use analytical functions:

```
 first_value(step) over (partition by value1 order by date_ desc)
```

`first_value (step)` tells Oracle that you want to get the *first value* of a list of steps. The elements and order of these is speciefied in the paranthesis after the `over` clause.

The "lists" are created with the `partition by value1`. Since there are two different value1's, two lists are created. The list belonging to *value1* constists of the elements A, B and C, the list belonging to *value2* of the elements A and B. These lists are ordered with the `order by date_ desc` clause.

Then, Oracle can "return" the first element of these lists.

See also [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80345/1)

Comment: @Rene...hi....this gives the maximum value of date...I waant the value of step corrwesponding to the maximum date in 4th coumn.

Comment: @Rene....Hi..It's perfect...thanks a lot...But when i have null instead of a date (ex.: 11.1.2014,12.2.2014,null), it's assuming null to be the maximum when we order by desc and giving the step corresponding to null instaed of corresponding to B. hope u got it

Comment: hi rene...i got it for that also...we need to use partition by value1 order by date_ desc nulls last...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You want the last value based on date.  You can do that with Oracle using an analytic function:

```
select Value1, step, date,
       max(step) keep (dense_rank last order by date) over (partition by value1) as maxval
from table t;
```

The important part here is the `keep` part and the part after that.  The `keep (dense_rank last order by date)` says to get the last value by date.  The `over (partition by value1)` says to do that within groups where `value1` has the same value.

Comment: @Gordon...Hi... I dont want to calculcate the maximum value of step...I want the value of step correspodning to the maximum date in each partition.

Comment: @VinodChelladurai . . . I realize that I originally misunderstood the question.  The answer should be correct now.

Comment: Hi..Gordan..thanks for the reply...I dont want to calculate the max of step..Since values of step need not be A,B,C always....

Comment: @VinodChelladurai . . . The `max()` is actually irrelevant.  It is part of the `keep` syntax.  Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi gordon...thanks for ur reply...it's considering the maximum value of step and giving a wrong output...:(

Comment: @VinodChelladurai . . . It works here on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a355/2).

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, they beat me to the punch....

Here's my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5775e/6)